# What's the Mandarin equivalent of the Hardcore History podcast?

Tags: history, listening

So I'm looking for an very interesting and in-depth history podcast, in Mandarin, for native speakers.

It's doesn't have to be about Chinese history, or any particular place or period. Any recommendations are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The BBC was running a podcast a few years ago, [20th Century China](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p02pcb35/episodes/downloads). It's in Mandarin and has 35 episodes in total.

[image]

---

RTHK hosted another Mandarin language show, but not as in-depth as you might would like, rather bite-sized: [中国历史小档案](http://podcast.rthk.hk/podcast/item_epi.php?pid=31)

[image]

If you speak Cantonese, they have more detailed shows on Chinese history, e.g. [神州五十年](http://podcast.rthk.hk/podcast/item_all.php?pid=155&lang=zh-CN). Check their [podcasts list](http://podcast.rthk.hk/podcast/list_audio.php?lang=zh-CN).